# Traduzir "tags" para rótulos

Tags: debate, status-recusado, tags

Dado que este sítio está em português, não devíamos usar "rótulos" ao invés de "tags"?

Comment: Eu acho que certas palavras não precisam ser traduzidas, principalmente aquelas que usamos no nosso dia-a-dia de programador, como tag, bug, browser, cross-browser, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Esta questão é válida e vai, provavelmente, acompanhar o SOpt sempre. A problemática é que temos ferramentas em Inglês (a maioria das linguagens de programação é em Inglês) mas referímos-nos a essa(s) ferramenta(s) em Português.

Para não criarmos um mundo paralelo (e talvez insustentável), sugiro que somente se adapte para a nossa língua termos que são raros ou complexos em Inglês, ou claro, termos que já estão adoptados na sua versão portuguesa como p.ex.: *Pilha/Array*

Neste caso da tradução de `tag` acho melhor deixar em Inglês. `Tag`parece-me bastante familiar (de uso frequente) em ambiente de programação e web.

No cenário em que *tag* seria *rótulo*, ou mesmo *etiqueta*, então em HTML diriamos "*um elemento de rótulo* `<div>`".
Parece-me complicar sem necessidade, uma vez que o termo já está enraizado com a versão Inglêsa.

Comment: Apesar de eu achar que essa questao merce ser expandida para outros escopos, falo aqui da funcao de "tagging" desse StackOverflow e da "tag" "tags". Deixo o emprego de "tag" em outros contextos para outra pergunta. Do meu ponto de vista, complicar é usar o termo ingles quando o em portugues cabe. Complica, por exemplo, quando quisermos nos referir à acao de etiquetar. Vamos falar "taguear"? Isso seria esdruxulo. Mas, nao adianta falamos de opinioes livremente sem considerar *regras* para isso. Hoje a duvida é sobre "tag", mas em breve será sobre "faq". Se nao ha regra, devemos criar.

Comment: @Ramiro, concordo que é preciso criar uma regra. Talvez melhor colocar uma pergunta sobre essa "regra geral" para nomes de elementos estruturais do site.

Answer (score 0):

Se fosse traduzir eu já partiria pra "etiquetas" então, que coincide com as traduções de sistemas operacionais e aplicativos. No entanto, acho que anglicismos mais enraizados, como "deletar" etc, (e mesmo *tags*) são inofensivos.

Comment: "Etiquetas" é uma tradução adequada também.